# Update view constraints in NSPopover OSX Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am on Xcode 8.2, Objective C, Mac OSX, not iOS.

I have a view shown in a popover like this:[image]

Once i select an option in the second NSPopupButton, the blue text gets replaced with another LONGER text (5 lines instead of 3) - Unfortunately the view doesn't grow to reflect the changes!

[image]

Only if i close the NSPopover and reopen it, the view is correct:

[image]

The view is completely built with autolayout and constraints. There's NO constraint limiting HEIGHT or WIDTH for any subview, just setting distances to superview. So my quesiton is, how can i update the view after a selection in the NSPopupButton. I already tried (in the viewController)

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout:YES];
```

But it seems not to work. I checked these posts but they did not help me with my issue:

[Resize current view using NSLayoutConstraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130136/resize-current-view-using-nslayoutconstraints)

**Edit:**

The new text (on NSPopupButton selection) is set like this:

`[self.descriptionTextField setStringValue:self.currentSequenceItem.descriptionText];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and i'd like to share it.
Once you've set all your constraints make sure to call

```
[yourTextField setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:100.0f]; // Whatever you need
```

Otherwise the textField will tend to scale horizontally making all your text a one liner.

If that property is set, it'll scale vertically and will update all constraints as excpected.